# CSS add bottom line to jQueryUI tabs

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

Please take a look at this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/p3sfy/3871/)**. I've overwritten `.ui-corner-all` with `{border-bottom-right-radius:0px;border-bottom-left-radius:0px;}` to remove the bottom radius corners of the top blue header, but it is also affecting the bottom of the tabs as well, where I want to add a thick border bottom line with radius corners. Kind of like this:

[image]

Any idea to add a different class for the tab bottom?

HTML:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Content for Tab 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Content for Tab 2</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Content for Tab 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The theme I'm using is Redmond.
The line I've added:

```
.ui-corner-all {border-bottom-right-radius:0px;border-bottom-left-radius:0px;}
```

Comment: I doubt if .ui-corner-all is the correct class. This class represent the style of the tab container i.e #tabs rather than each tab. You need to manipulate the class tab class

Comment: add the border-bottom code to this .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav to hide border bottom of the top nav alone

Answer (score 0):

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: .2em .2em 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
 }
```

The above code removes the rounded corner from the bottom of the top blue nav alone.

`.ui-corner-all` is common throughout the tabs that's why its affecting both.